# What happens to the digital games and xbox gold live account if I want to buy new xbox or my xbox is dead?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

What happens to the digital games and xbox gold live account if I want to buy new xbox ?

I sold my xbox one and I still want to use the digital games and the live account I had with my previous one ? How would I do it ?

Are those things tied with the console or account ?

Answer (score 4):

If you login with same account on the new Xbox you buy, you should be able to access all your games and your xbox live subscription.

Those things are tied to your account, not your console.

Comment: I read somewhere it get tied with console and the account. If its only account, thats gonna help a lot.

Comment: @hsuk it is **just** the account.

Comment: @BlueBarren not necessarily. I forget how it works exactly, but something with how you setup the Home Console affects this I think.  But, if you have just a single account, any purchases made on that account should transfer right over to another Xbox if you purchase another

Comment: @TimmyJim all setting a home console does is it allows other users to access content purchased with another account on that account's home Xbox.  So if I buy any kind of content, games, dlc, etc. and you go on my home Xbox you can use that content freely.  Where as if I sign into your Xbox but it's not my home Xbox only I can access my purchased content.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is tied to your account **and** to a minor extend, your Xbox One.

**As long as you have access to your account, you can always re-download and replay all of the games you own digitally** as well as all savegames that were saved to the cloud. As you sold your console, I'd also suggest you change your account password or the owner of your old console may have access to your account.

The Xbox One was the first console to let you set a *Home Console*. What that meant is that, on this console, all other tags on that console could play your content, as in your digital library, even if your tag wasn't logged into that console. This also holds true for sharing your Gold membership.

However, once you get a new console with that feature (Xbox One family), you can log in with your account and then set that console as your home console. It will then be revoked from the other console as you can only have at most one *Home Console*.